# Saving messages from different topics to different files in Alpakka

Tags: akka-stream, alpakka

I'm trying to figure out how to pass messages from a Kafka consumer subscribed to multiple topics to a processing stage based on a topic (e.g. save them to a specific file or a database or whatever).

There is a `Consumer.externalCommittableSource` but it requires manually selecting partitions which is something I want to avoid.

In general, what is the proper way to dynamically create flows and sinks based on a value of some grouping attribute of stream elements?

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are looking for the [`groupBy`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/groupBy.html#groupby) operator.

Comment: `groupBy` doesn't allow to provide a specific processing stage for each subflow, I've solved the problem using `BroadcastHub`